# Exec format error 32-bit executable Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: gcc, executable, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 32-bit, executable-format

When I try to execute a 32-bit file compiled with `gcc -m32 main.c -o main` on *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, I get the following error: `bash: ./main: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

If I compile it *without* `-m32` it runs.

Any solution for **running 32-bit executable on WSL**?

Comment: `.c` and `.s` are source code files. They cannot be executed directly and they are typically not the output of a C compiler or assembler program.

Comment: I know, I meant that I compile a main.c file and execute the 32 bit executable ./main

Comment: I am not certain enough of this to post it as an answer, but I *believe* WSL is, itself, a 64-bit process. You can't run a 32-bit executable (or load a 32-bit library) in a 64-bit process.

Comment: Related: WSL doesn't support 32-bit `int 0x80` system calls in 64-bit executables, so building asm as 64-bit doesn't help unless you also use the proper `syscall`  system call ABI.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

32-bit ELF support isn't provided by WSL (yet). There doesn't seem to be any progress since the UserVoice was raised - you are out luck.

See [UserVoice: Please add 32 bit ELF support to the kernel](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13377507-please-add-32-bit-elf-support-to-the-kernel) and [Support for 32-bit i386 ELF binaries](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/390).

If possible, switch to a *real* Linux ;-)

---

Since this was originally posted, the support has been available on WSL2 which does support [real Linux kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#full-linux-kernel)! So that should be the preferred way.

As noted in the linked [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/390#issuecomment-480627111), there's also `qemu-user` which can be used if WSL1 is still used.

Comment: This answer appears to be outdated.

Comment: See also [Does WSL 2 really support 32 bit program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300194) re: how to actually make sure your WSL is WSL2.  Apparently some people think they have WSL2 but 32-bit executables still don't work because it's actually WSL1.

Answer (score 48):

QEMU and binfmt support light the way :)

https://github.com/microsoft/wsl/issues/2468#issuecomment-374904520

After reading that the WSLInterop between WSL and Windows processes used binfmt, I was tinkering with QEMU to try some ARM development, and incidentally discovered how to get 32-bit support working.

Edit: requires "Fall Creators Update", 1709, build 16299 or newer

Install qemu and binfmt config:

```
sudo apt install qemu-user-static
sudo update-binfmts --install i386 /usr/bin/qemu-i386-static --magic '\x7fELF\x01\x01\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00' --mask '\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xfc\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf8\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```

You'll need to reactivate binfmt support every time you start WSL:

```
sudo service binfmt-support start
```

Enable i386 architecture packages:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc:i386
```

Try it out:

```
$ file /usr/bin/gcc-5
/usr/bin/gcc-5: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=2637bb7cb85f8f12b40f03cd015d404930c3c790, stripped

$ /usr/bin/gcc-5 --version
gcc-5 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld

$ ./helloworld
Hello, world!

$ file helloworld
helloworld: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=3a0c7be5c6a8d45613e4ef2b7b3474df6224a5da, not stripped
```

And to prove it really was working, disable i386 support and try again:

```
$ sudo service binfmt-support stop
 * Disabling additional executable binary formats binfmt-support [ OK ]

$ ./helloworld
-bash: ./helloworld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Comment: works for me, WIN10   1803, WSL,  ubuntu 18.04 LTS  linux

g++-8

Comment: Works great, thanks! Windows 10 v1803 WSL Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If I have installed 64bit gcc, then when I run `sudo apt install gcc:i386`, it gave me the following errors: ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc:i386 : Depends: cpp:i386 (>= 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: gcc-7:i386 (>= 7.3.0-27~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```
I will try to use the method mention here (https://askubuntu.com/questions/510269/how-to-install-build-essentiali386-to-compile-a-32-bit-executable-on-a-64-bit-s#answer-828458)

Comment: I'm not great at handling apt install issues so I keep several WSL installs around for different needs (e.g. i386 vs x64, etc). Separate chroot/containers should do the job too, as you referenced.

Comment: For WSL OpenSuse put `qemu-i386-binfmt` (from 'qemu-linux-user' package) instead of `qemu-i386-static` in the update-binfmts line.

Comment: I need to uninstall the 64bit version of gcc then install 32bit.

Comment: Works great for me in order to execute 32-bit binaries on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 LTS built with g++ v7.40 using `-m32` compiler flag. In essence, all that is required for running 32-bit binaries is the `apt install qemu-user-static`, `update-binfmts --install i386 ...`, and `service binfmt-support start`. 
gcc:i386 is not required since you can cross compile for x86 using gcc-multilib

Comment: This works without the "sudo apt install gcc:i386" step. I tried installing gcc:i386 and it wanted to delete all my 64-bit compiler packages and replace them with 32-bit ones. No thanks.

Answer (score 10):

[WSL2 runs in a *real* virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-about?WT.mc_id=thomasmaurer-blog-thmaure) using a [*real* Linux kernel](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel), therefore it's actually possible to do anything a Linux VM can do, including running 32-bit code. Just install 32-bit libs by running

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

For more information read

- [Announcing WSL 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/)
- [WSL 2 FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq)

Comment: You may also need `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6:i386`, as per http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.95/install.html#install-64

Comment: That's right, it doesn't work without the install line.