# GDB does not step correctly

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, elf

Why does GDB not go to the next machine instruction. In the gif below, I set the program counter to point to start (0x100020), which holds the `cli` instruction. However, when I enter `(gdb) stepi`, GDB does not go to the next instruction which is (0x100021) `mov $0x104000,%esp`, but instead jumps to (0x100023).

Regardless of which instruction I start with, GDB does not jump to the next logical instruction, and instead jumps to a seemingly arbitrary location. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Try the command `nexti`

Comment: @Sergio, same problem of arbitrary jump. Further I need `stepi` to work as want to follow all instructions as they execute.

Answer (score 1):

> 32-bit ELF support isn't provided by WSL (yet).

See the [following StackOverfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121153).

Turns out WSL is the problem, my elf file is 32 bit.

---

**EDIT**

While the above is true, 32-bit elf debugging through GDB is possible in WSL if you use QEMU. In my case, GDB was behaving as above not because it was a 32-bit (as I was running the elf file through QEMU) but because the code produced by my assembler did not produce debugging information that GDB understood. I was using [NASM](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html) and the `-F dwarf` and `-g` flags were needed to produce said debugging information.

Comment: GDB doesn't need debug info for `stepi` / `nexti`.  Was it getting confused by *wrong* debug info?  It looks like you were using `layout reg` or `layout asm` (so you were seeing a disassembly window, not a source window).  What I'd be worried about is if `cli` stops debug-interrupts from firing.