# x86 Assembly Program's binary executable does not run on Kali WSL

Tags: linux, assembly, binary, nasm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am starting to learn x86 Assembly Programming, following this [Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm) and I wrote a Hello World Program saved as hello.asm

```
section .text
   global _start

_start:
   mov  edx,len
   mov  ecx,msg
   mov  ebx,1
   mov  eax,4
   int  0x80

   mov  eax,1
   int  0x80

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa
len equ $ - msg
```

I then used nasm as

> nasm -f elf32 hello.asm

and got the object file hello.o

then I used ld as

> ld -m elf_i386 -o hello hello.o

I then got the hello binary file, executing it with ./hello I get

> ./hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I have 64 bit OS,output of "uname -a"

> uname -a
>
> Linux DESKTOP-JO8V9QJ 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL #1 SMP Fri Apr
> 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux

the hello binary file is 32 bit , output of file ./hello is

> file ./hello
>
> ./hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
> statically linked, not stripped

Now x64 is supposed to be Backward Compatible, that means it should be able to run this binary... My Question is , is there a problem in the Code or is there something wrong with my instance of Kali on WSL which I am using to execute this because [WSL has Given me Problems earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69656217/puts-all-command-line-input-in-a-single-array-element-in-bash) and what is the solution for this"Exec Format Error" ?

Other stack overflow articles come close to this issue but nothing related to running it on WSL...

**EDIT 1:**
wsl -l -v gives

> NAME          STATE           VERSION
>
> - kali-linux    Running         1

and I didn't knew that WSL doesnt Support 32 bit so , Upgrded to WSL2 and it works perfectly.....

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds could use some help here........

Comment: Look like you need to do some special [hoop jumping](https://github.com/microsoft/wsl/issues/2468) to get this working.

Comment: The simple solution is to write 64 bit code.

Comment: @HrithikRaj Oh, it's been way too many decades since I've done any assembly ;-).  But yes, see the Github issue that 500 posted, but realize that it starts with WSL1 a few years back.  Also note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67782451/11810933).

Comment: [Does WSL 2 really support 32 bit program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300194) shows how to check that you're really fully using WSL2, not WSL1 which doesn't support 32-bit programs.  Your `uname -a` has a kernel version name ending with WSL2, but I don't know if that's definitive.  You'd hope it would be, but given the error you're getting, it appears not.  Those are the right build commands.

Comment: @Peter Cordes: `Linux DESKTOP-JO8V9QJ 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux` Where does this say WSL2 ?

Comment: @ecm: 7 minutes ago, it said WSL2 instead of WSL.  Apparently the querent somehow added a 2 when copy/pasting it, or copy/pasted from the wrong thing, and just edited it after my comment made them double-check.

Comment: @PeterCordes that 2 was an error i edited it now and Installed WSL 2 and the program works .....thanks